# "export 'Δinject' was not found in '@angular/core'

Tags: angular6, angular7

Showing some warnings in ng serve.

> export 'ΔdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core' export
>
> 'Δinject' was not found in '@angular/core'

Removed  @angular/cdk  and  @angular/material.

**My package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "github:angular/animations-builds",
  "@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
  "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
  "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
  "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
  "@angular/material": "github:angular/material2-builds",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
  "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
  "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
  "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.17",
  "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.8.1",
  "@ng-select/ng-select": "2.16.4",
  "@types/auth0-js": "^8.11.11",
  "angular-datatables": "^7.0.0"
```

}

**On ng serve,**  getting these kinda errors.

> WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/observers.es5.js 38:65-82
> "export 'ΔdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/observers.es5.js 195:57-74
> "export 'ΔdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/collections.es5.js 524:67-84
> "export 'ΔdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 527:168-175
> "export 'Δinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 527:195-202
> "export 'Δinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 527:219-226
> "export 'Δinject' was not found in '@angular/core'

Comment: i have same error. you solved?

Answer (score -1):

Go back to v7 release:

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout@7.0.0-beta.24
```

The `beta.25` is meant for Angular 8, though it has few problems on its own so I would recommend to wait a while until Angular 8 goes out of RC.